# Modify Django forms.Textarea in template or always in models

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a forms.Form in models with a textarea:

```
answer1 = forms.CharField(label='Answer 1', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"placeholder":"Type your answer...", "rows":6, "cols":45}), max_length=150)
```

In views:

```
...
form = SurveyForm(request.POST)
...
...render(...{'form':form})
```

And my template:

```
<p><label>Answer 1:</label> {{ form.answer1 }}</p>
```

But now i want to use javascript to get a counter with number of chars left. So my textarea needs some additional information e.g. something like this:

```
onKeyDown="MyCountFunction('textbox','char',150)"
```

Do i have to add all informations about a textarea to my forms.Form like i did with placeholder or is there a way of adding this somewhere in my templates. Whats the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like jQuery for this, check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) on `keydown()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: initial

```
if request.user ==  discussion.owner:
  description_form = UpdateDiscussionForm(initial={'description': discussion.description})
  add_decision_form = AddDecisionForm()
```

[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)